# Cannot download & install old OpenDayLight versions

Tags: maven, sdn, opendaylight

I need to download an old ODL version for testing (Helium  release in this case), but when I tried to build ODL with maven, it failed to download `opendaylight.odlparent:odlparent:pom:1.4.7-SNAPSHOT` from [nexus repository](http://ylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/) (it seems old versions <3.0.4 were purged) and stopped.

Where can I download Helium ODL and run successfully?

Step to reproduce error:

```
git clone -b stable/helium https://github.com/opendaylight/controller.git
cd controller/
mvn clean install
```

> [ERROR]   The project org.opendaylight.controller:opendaylight-karaf-resources:[unknown-version] (/[...]/controller/opendaylight/distribution/opendaylight-karaf-resources/pom.xml) has 1 error
>
> [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.opendaylight.controller:commons.opendaylight:1.4.7-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.opendaylight.odlparent:odlparent:pom:1.4.7-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of opendaylight-snapshot has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ org.opendaylight.controller:commons.opendaylight:1.4.7-SNAPSHOT, /[...]/controller/opendaylight/commons/opendaylight/pom.xml, line 4, column 11 -> [Help 2]

EDIT: [This answer](https://ask.opendaylight.org/question/12024/maven-build-of-opendaylight-helium-code/) said SNAPSHOT releases had short lives, so for older versions one need to build all dependencies himself, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do "git clone -b stable/helium ..." and build every project that the controller project depends on. For Helium I believe it's only odlparent and yangtools.